# How to measure Excel Calculation times

Tags: performance, excel, excel-formula, processing-efficiency, array-formulas

For example how could I find what formula is faster?

```
=SUMPRODUCT((Data!D:D="RC Corp")*(Data!AD:AD="Expected Allowances / Provisions"))
```

Vs

```
=COUNTIFS(Data!D:D,"RC Corp",Data!AD:AD,"Expected Allowances / Provisions")
```

Vs Concatinating the 2 fields into a new Column and doing

```
 Z1 = D1&AD1
=Countif(Data!Z:Z,"RC CorpExpected Allowances / Provisions")
```

Vs VBA

```
Dim i as integer
Dim Total as integer
Total = 0 
i=0
While i < 1000 
    IF Range("D"&i).Value = "RC Corp" AND Range("AD"&i).Value = "Expected Allowances / Provisions" Then
Total = Total + 1
End If 
Wend
Range("$A$1").Value = Total
```

Comment: I would do the following: Use the methods described [here](http://www.codematic.net/excel-development/excel-vba/excel-vba-performance.htm) and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff700514(v=office.14).aspx) to speed up performance. To test formula performance: set a benchmark by timing repeated cycles of turning off auto-recalc,writing a string (or other constant into a cell, and turning recalc back on; do same for your formulas, i.e., turning off recalc, write formula to cell, and recalc'ing the cell or the sheet. Haven't tried this myself so putting this in as comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Woking from evocandy's answer I came up with this basic code.

```
time1 = Timer
Range("A1").Calculate ' Or the cell containing the Formula I want. OR use Sheets("Sheet1").Calculate for the calculation including concated columns
time2 = Timer

CalculationTime = Time2-Time1
```

In order for this to work i had to Isolate sample data to new empty worksheets and disable the Automatic Refresh in Excel as to make sure it doesn't time any other Calculations.

Answer (score 3):

In VBA you can user `Timer`.

Put

```
time1 = Timer
'Your code
time2 = timer

totaltime = time2-time1
```

Comment: I under stand how to do this for VBA CODE, but how would i measure calculations done in forumlas out side of VBA?

Comment: [**Here**](http://sites.mcpher.com/share/Home/excelquirks/optimizationlink) is another resource on measuring formula performance from a great site on all sorts of advanced Excel techniques.

Comment: chuff both of your links seem to be strictly for VBA

Comment: @user2140261 Without VBA, you can fill a lot of cells with the same formula, and count calculation time with a stopwatch.  Usually, you will need at least tens to hundreds of thousands cells, if not millions.